# complex analysis conjugate problem

Tags: complex-numbers

Is it equal? Or is it not equal? Also I tried two way. Logarithmic and polar representation. But I failed. Sorry for my English.
I couldn't show this.

$$\overline{(z^{z})} \neq \bar{z}^{\bar{z}}$$
$$\overline{(z^{z})} = \bar{z}^{\bar{z}}$$

Comment: Since there are infinitely many values of $z^z$, it's not clear what you mean.  Are you asking if each of the values of the left-hand side is equal to one of the values of the right-hand side, or if some value of the LHS is equal to some value of the RHS?

Comment: In fact, is it always equal to ask? Is there a situation that distorts equality or inequality?

Comment: "is it always equal to ask" -- Huh?  In any event, my answer shows you how to do this.  Just take $z=re^{i\theta}$ and do similar calculations.

Answer (score 2):

Take the case $z=i$.  Then $$z^z=i^i=e^{i\log{i}}=e^{i(i2n\pi+i\pi/2)}=e^{-2n\pi-\pi/2}$$ Since this is real, for all integer values of $n$, we have $\overline{z^z}=z^z$ in this case.  On the other hand, 
$$\overline{z}^{\overline{z}}=(-i)^{-i}=e^{-i(i2k\pi-i\pi/2)}=e^{-2k\pi+\pi/2}$$  There are no integer values of $k$ and $n$ such that $-2n\pi-\pi/2=-2k\pi+\pi/2$, so in the case $z=i$, there is no value of the left-hand side equal to any value of the right-hand side.

Therefore, as a general rule, $\overline{z^z}\neq\overline{z}^{\overline{z}}$.  Of course, they're equal when $z$ is real.